# WebAPI issue while retrieving data from database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I created a Project to learn about web api and entity framework. Well, when I try to connect my service with the database, the service did not retrieve the data from database. Below is my connection string:

```
<add name="CotacaoContext" connectionString="Data Source=Minha_Maquina\Instancia; Initial Catalog=Cotacao; User Id=sa; Password=d123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is my controller and the method GetUsuarios. This method(GetUsuarios) retrieves all data from DB(Table=Usuarios).

```
public class UsuarioController : ApiController
{
    private CotacaoContext contexto = new CotacaoContext("CotacaoContext");

    [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
    public IEnumerable<Usuarios> GetUsuarios()
    {
        return contexto.Usuario.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public Usuarios GetUsuarioById(int id)
    {
        Usuarios usuario = contexto.Usuario.Find(id);
        if(usuario == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return usuario;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        contexto.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Context class with respective DBSet:

```
public class CotacaoContext : DbContext
{
    public CotacaoContext()
        : base("name=CotacaoContext")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Usuarios> Usuario { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Login> Login { get; set; }
}
```

model class

```
public class Usuarios
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Tipo_Usuario { get; set; }
    public string NMUsuario { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
}
```

When I debug this line

```
return contexto.Usuario.AsEnumerable();
```

I have this problem:

[image]

my table has 6 records and in the image 6 records appear in this format "**?**". 
What does it mean?

Comment: That looks like a bug in the debugger.  Do you have any actual problem?

Comment: Yes, because my list is null and in my database I have 6 records. In the Postman or Browser, I have this: [].

Comment: As @SLaks said, it is a [known bug in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918981/get-question-mark-instead-property-name-and-value-in-debug-mode-in-visual-studio). You said you have 6 records, are they null, or do they have the values you would expect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001023/what-do-question-marks-in-visual-studio-watch-window-signify

Comment: Ok, is a bug, but why in the Postman i have a null value? In the Postman i have this [] so my array is null. If this issue were the debug, i think would have something in the array, that's ok?

Comment: @pkt First you should use ToList() to defer execute the query. You have [] because your are returning a empty list.

Comment: @Fals, thanks. I'm learning Web Api and Entity. This is a exercice with Web Api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.I needed only a ToList() like this:

```
return contexto.Usuario.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

I saw this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158753/entity-framework-is-throwing-an-error-unable-to-evaluate-the-expression-operat)